# Identifying 24hour periods in GPS data

Tags: r

I would like to identify sequential 24 hour periods in GPS data. I have a datetime column that is numerical (ex: 41422.29) and I know each rounded number is a day. I know how to get the day (just round), however my schedule does not specifically follow days. Instead, I would specifically like to identify all of the columns that are within 24 hours from the first column, and then go from there. I can not use a count of columns, as 24 hours is not divided into equal increments.

This is my logic so far, though it doesn't get me where I need to be:

```
for (i in 1:length(example)){
base<-round(example$DT_LMT[i], digits=0)  
if(example$DT_LMT[i]<=base+1) {
    example$DaySeq<-base
  }
  else {
    base+1
  }
}
```

I have a dummy data set example, with the kind of thing I would like:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:19, DT_LMT = c(41423.62517, 41423.79236, 
41423.95868, 41424.12534, 41424.29203, 41424.45888, 41424.62535, 
41424.79186, 41424.95852, 41425.12502, 41425.29185, 41425.75016, 
41425.79201, 41425.83352, 41425.87534, 41425.91744, 41425.95868, 
41426.00105, 41426.04257), NEED = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"DT_LMT", "NEED"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach, assuming `df` is the data assigned in your question. I created a new variable, `need` which I believe is your desired outcome.

```
transform(df, need = trunc(DT_LMT - DT_LMT[1]) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add 1 to the first value as the filter the data frame.

```
data<-data.frame(ID = 1:19, DT_LMT = c(41423.62517, 41423.79236, 
                                     41423.95868, 41424.12534, 41424.29203, 41424.45888, 41424.62535, 
                                     41424.79186, 41424.95852, 41425.12502, 41425.29185, 41425.75016, 
                                     41425.79201, 41425.83352, 41425.87534, 41425.91744, 41425.95868, 
                                     41426.00105, 41426.04257), NEED = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L))

data[data$DT_LMT<=data$DT_LMT[1]+1,]
```

Output:

```
  ID   DT_LMT NEED
1  1 41423.63    1
2  2 41423.79    1
3  3 41423.96    1
4  4 41424.13    1
5  5 41424.29    1
6  6 41424.46    1
```

If you want to split the data into a list by 24 hour period.

```
split(data,unlist(lapply(data$DT_LMT,function(x){floor(x-data$DT_LMT[1])})))
```

Output:

```
$`0`
  ID   DT_LMT NEED
1  1 41423.63    1
2  2 41423.79    1
3  3 41423.96    1
4  4 41424.13    1
5  5 41424.29    1
6  6 41424.46    1

$`1`
   ID   DT_LMT NEED
7   7 41424.63    2
8   8 41424.79    2
9   9 41424.96    2
10 10 41425.13    2
11 11 41425.29    2

$`2`
   ID   DT_LMT NEED
12 12 41425.75    3
13 13 41425.79    3
14 14 41425.83    3
15 15 41425.88    3
16 16 41425.92    3
17 17 41425.96    3
18 18 41426.00    3
19 19 41426.04    3
```

To add a column with the day.

```
data$day<-lapply(data$DT_LMT,function(x){floor(x-data$DT_LMT[1])+1})
```